# Kafka brokers not starting up

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 2 broker cluster of `kafka 0.10.1` running up previously on my development servers with `zookeeper 3.3.6` correctly.

I recently tried upgrading broker version to latest `kafka 2.3.0` but it didn't start.
There is nothing much changed in the configuration.
Can anybody direct me what possibly could go wrong. Why brokers are not getting started?

**Changed server.properties** on broker server 1

```
broker.id=1
log.dirs=/mnt/kafka_2.11-2.3.0/logs
zookeeper.connect=local1:2181,local2:2181
listeners=PLAINTEXT://local1:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://local1:9092
```

**Changed server.properties** on broker server 2

```
broker.id=2
log.dirs=/mnt/kafka_2.11-2.3.0/logs
zookeeper.connect=local1:2181,local2:2181
listeners=PLAINTEXT://local2:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://local2:9092
```

**NOTE**:
1. Zookeeper is running on both servers
2. Kafka directories namely `/brokers, /brokers/ids, /consumers` etc are getting created.
3. Nothing is getting registered under /brokers/ids. Zookeeper CLI `get /brokers/ids` returns
   `[]`
4. Command `lsof -i tcp:9082` returns
`COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    18290      cass  118u  IPv6  52133      0t0  TCP local2:9092 (LISTEN)`
4. `logs/server.log` has no errors logged.
5. No more logs are getting appended to `server.log`.

**Server logs**

> [2019-07-01 10:56:14,534] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
>   [2019-07-01 10:56:14,801] INFO Awaiting socket connections on local2:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
>   [2019-07-01 10:56:14,829] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Created data-plane acceptor and processors for endpoint : EndPoint(local2,9092,ListenerName(PLAINTEXT),PLAINTEXT) (kafka.network.SocketServer)
>   [2019-07-01 10:56:14,830] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Started 1 acceptor threads for data-plane (kafka.network.SocketServer)
>   [2019-07-01 10:56:14,850] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
>   [2019-07-01 10:56:14,851] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
>   [2019-07-01 10:56:14,851] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1-DeleteRecords]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
>   [2019-07-01 10:56:14,852] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1-ElectPreferredLeader]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
>   [2019-07-01 10:56:14,860] INFO [LogDirFailureHandler]: Starting (kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler)
>   [2019-07-01 10:56:14,892] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/1 (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs regarding ZooKeeper
Stable version

> The current stable branch is 3.4 and the latest release of that branch is 3.4.9.

Upgrading zookeeper version to latest `3.5.5` helped and Kafka broker started correctly.
It would have been great if docs had stated the incompatibility with previous zookeeper version.
PS: Answer added to help someone struck with similar issue because of zookeeper version.